# What is the appropiate way to define a react component class without state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm wondering if the recommended way to define a react class component with typescript is using a void as state type:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<any, void> {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      // The typescript compiler won't allow this using void type
      // this.state = {...}
   [...]
}
```

Do you know a recommended or better way?

Note: the component must be a class because I will need the lifecycle methods

Comment: what's wrong with defining the component this way?

Comment: It's ok but I was looking for some kind of official way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its perfectly legal to use `void` as state type. I have not seen any "official" recommendations for stateless components based on classes, but (if this will make you feel safer) this approach is used by some not so small [projects](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/docs/react_concepts.html).

You can use `{}` instead of `void` but this will not protect you from assigning something to state.

It is also possible to specify `never` and it seems to give the same results as `void`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have heard of the never type, I will try it. I don't know if conceptually is better than a void either

Comment: My personal preference is to use `void` as it better "describes" your intent.